# how to toggle several properties

Tags: javascript, html, dom, dom-manipulation

I have to toggle classes of buttons and parent element (cards)

```
let btns = document.querySelectorAll('.btn-primary');
btns.forEach(btn => {
  btn.addEventListener('click', function(e){
    e.target.parentElement.classList.toggle('red');
    e.target.classList.toggle('green');
  });
});
```

But, actually, the card and button does not change the class at the same time. Card gets red color but button gets green after I click another button.

Comment: The code is working... please, check https://jsfiddle.net/qzxcv10b/2/

Answer (score 0):

You can extend click function a bit and decide if all buttons should also contain green class

```js
let btns = document.querySelectorAll('.btn-primary');
btns.forEach(btn => {
  btn.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    const parentElement = e.target.parentElement;
    const element = e.target;

    for (let button of document.querySelectorAll('.btn-primary')) {
    if(button === element){
    continue
    }
      if (button.classList.contains('green')) {
        button.classList.toggle('green');
      }
    }

    element.classList.toggle('green');
    
    if([...document.querySelectorAll('.btn-primary')].some(element => element.classList.contains('green'))) {
    parentElement.classList.add('red');
    }
    else {
    parentElement.classList.remove('red');
    }
    
  });
});
```

```css
.parent {
  padding: 1rem;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.parent.red {
  border-color: red;
}

.green {
  color: green;
}

.red {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <button class="btn-primary">Test</button>
  <button class="btn-primary">Test</button>
</div>
```